Which is the meaning of $\lim_{(x,y)\to\infty}f(x,y)$?
$$(x,y)\to\infty$$
Doing things about limits I often came across this writing. Sometimes online, like here, and sometimes my Analysis teacher has used it too.
What is the meaning of this writing?
Does this mean that both x and y must grow so that |x|=|y|? Or like does it mean I can take any curve as long as it diverges?
Furthermore, for functions with $n\ge 2$ variables does it have the same meaning?

It the intuition is that for all points far enough you're close to the limit. Explicitly we say $\lim_{(x,y)\to\infty}f(x,y)=L$ if
$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists M>0):||(x,y)||>M\implies |f(x,y)-L|<\varepsilon$$

I don't want to hijack the question with a similar answer, but I think being precise is important: Given a real number $L$ and a scalar function $f$ defined in an open subset $D$ of $\mathbb R^2$, we say that $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to \infty}\left(f(x,y)\right)=L$, if, by definition,
$$\mathop{\forall}{\varepsilon > 0}\mathop{\exists}{M>0}\mathop{\forall}_{(x,y)\in D}\left(\left\Vert(x,y)\right\Vert>M\implies \vert f(x,y)-L\vert<\varepsilon\right)$$

Personally, I don't even like the notation $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to \infty}\left(f(x,y)\right)$, preferring $\lim \limits_{\infty}\left(f\right)$ instead.

@GitGud alright

Things like $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}$ are just as ambiguous as this notation; if you have taken an analysis or calculus course you were probably taught that we require all paths to $(a,b)$ to have the same limit. Here, we require all paths that diverge to infinity, no matter how they diverge, to have the same limit. To answer your questions

If the limit exists you may take any path that diverges to infinity, and it will give the same answer (this is more or less the definition of such a limit existing)
Yes, the notion is similar for $n \geq 2$.

A last topological note: there are a few ways to think about this sort of notation but one I like: with the standard topology on the n-dimensional sphere $S^n$, we get that taking away one point gives us the Euclidean space topology $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the subspace topology. We can think of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as like a sphere with a point removed, that point being $\infty$. This more or less makes convergence to a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the same as convergence to any other point. If you do not have any exposure to topology it is fine to treat them separately, but know that there is nothing particularly funky going on here.

Thanks for your answer. Actually i’m also taking a geometry course where i’m learning those thing, so yeah i got what i mean. Your comment opened my mind.

I disagree with the first phrase of this answer, in the sense that in 1d it's common to work with the extended reals where $\infty$ is not the same as $-\infty$. Notation like this has extra ambiguity in the sense that you need to know that the $\infty$ being referred to is suddenly the one in the one-point compactification of the plane rather than, say, something for the first quadrant or whatever.
